# Use AVAssetWriter to export uncompressed CVPixelBuffer

Tags: swift, avfoundation, video-processing

I am using ScreenCaptureKit to capture screen on macOS and everything works fine.

Now I want to export the CVPixelBuffer coming from ScreenCaptureKit using AVAssetWriter to a mp4 file but struggling with the quality of the export file.

When I convert the CVPixelBuffer from the captured frames into NSImage and write them to local disk, I don't see any lost of quality, so I assume that the frame is captured without any compression.

This is my setup for AVAssetWriter. I have tried different combination of the settings but the quality of the exported video still quite bad.

```swift
// Create a new AVAssetWriter to write the captured recording
// to a new file.
videoFileWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(url: prepareVideoOutputURL(), fileType: AVFileType.mp4)

let outputSettings: [String : Any] = [
    AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.hevc ,
    AVVideoHeightKey: frame.size.height - CGFloat(Self.topCropHeightWithoutScalingInPixels)/scaleFactor,
    AVVideoWidthKey: frame.size.width,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [
        AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey: false,
        AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: numberOfFramePerSecond,
        AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: numberOfFramePerSecond,
        AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalDurationKey: 1
    ],
    // HD Color space https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2227/_index.html
    // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_reading_and_writing/tagging_media_with_video_color_information
    AVVideoColorPropertiesKey: [
        AVVideoColorPrimariesKey: AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_709_2,
        AVVideoTransferFunctionKey: AVVideoTransferFunction_ITU_R_709_2,
        AVVideoYCbCrMatrixKey: AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2
    ]
]

videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(
    mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
    outputSettings: outputSettings,
    sourceFormatHint: nil
)
if videoFileWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) {
    videoFileWriter.add(videoWriterInput)
}

videoWriterInputAdapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(
    assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput,
    sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil
)
```

This is the frame converted into NSImage and saved as PNG, the quality is good: [image]

But this is the screen of a frame from the exported video, the quality is worse: [image]

Comment: You haven't set a video bitrate with `AVVideoAverageBitRateKey`. I'm don't know what the default is, but it might might be low.

Comment: what'd be recommended value for that setting? assuming I want to export a uncompressed video?

Comment: hello, im new macos developer, i see example ScreenCaptureKit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screencapturekit/capturing_screen_content_in_macos
how to save the stream to the video yaa?